# Partition function of atoms adsorbed on a surface

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I have the following problem in basic statistical physics, and the following doubts on my interpretation.

An ideal gas ($N$ atoms, chemical potential $\mu$) is in contact with an adsorbent lattice ($N_a$ adsorption sites).
Each adsorption site can be empty (energy $E=0$) or occupied by 1 atom (binding energy $E=-\varepsilon$, $\varepsilon>0$).

The lattice sites are distinguishable and independant and $N_a$ is fixed. Thus, one can find the grand partition function for the entire lattice with $Z_G=(z_G)^{N_a}$, where $z_G$ is the *grand partition function for the states at a single adsorption site*.

**My attempt to find $z_G$:**

I note that $z_G$ is the sum of two situations: an empty site (Boltzmann factor  $e^0=1$) and a site occupied by a particle of chemical potential $\mu$, corresponding to an energy $E=-\varepsilon$ (Boltzmann factor $e^{-\beta\varepsilon}e^{\beta\mu}$).

So, $$z_G=1+e^{\beta(\mu-\varepsilon)}.$$

**My question:**

I have an expression for $z_G$, but I would like to know how to find I $z_G$ from the canonical partition function, namely by using the formula $$z_G=\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}z_Ne^{\beta\mu N},$$
where $z_N$ is the canonical partition function for the states at one adsorption site.

It is not clear to me how this formula could be used in that case. Can we find a $z_N$ depending on $N$, the number of gas atoms, which would allow it to work? It seems to me that $N$ is the only number which can fluctuate and require the grand canonical ensemble.

Thank you very much for your help!